# How to convert more than one array to one array

Tags: php, laravel

I try to scrape a currency rate from [www.bi.go.id](http://www.bi.go.id), my code like this

```
$client     = new Client();
$crawler    = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/default.aspx');
$_data      = $crawler->filter('table[class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-lg"] > tbody > tr')->each(function ($node) {
   $explode = explode('\n', $node->text());
   print_r($explode);
});
```

my problem it return a more than one array, how can i make this result to just one array and convert it to json

```
Array
(
    [0] => AUD 1 9.692,41 9.588,34
)
Array
(
    [0] => BND 1 10.753,75 10.646,01
)
Array
(
    [0] => CAD 1 11.173,37 11.058,20
)
Array
(
    [0] => CHF 1 15.444,59 15.281,75
)
Array
(
    [0] => CNH 1 2.145,88 2.124,29
)
Array
(
    [0] => CNY 1 2.146,68 2.124,79
)
```

Comment: You can use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: You can use the ``Arr::flatten`` method provided by the Laravel framework.

Comment: `$_data      = $crawler->filter('table[class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-lg"] > tbody > tr')->each(function ($node) {
           $explode = explode('\n', $node->text());
            print_r(Arr::flatten($explode));
});
`

i use this but still get same return

Comment: Spread the exploded data while pushing: [How to merge two arrays without adding another index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815010/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a collection then append items with [push](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-push), at last for converting to JSON use [toJson](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-tojson):

```php
$rows = collect();
$_data = $crawler->filter('table[class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-lg"] > tbody > tr')
    ->each(fn ($node) => $rows->push(explode('\n', $node->text())[0]));

$rows->toJson();
```

Comment: `["AUD 1 9.692,41 9.588,34"]["BND 1 10.753,75 10.646,01"]["CAD 1 11.173,37 11.058,20"]["CHF 1 15.444,59 15.281,75"]["CNH 1 2.145,88 2.124,29"]["CNY 1 2.146,68 2.124,79"]` i try that  but i get result like this

Comment: what is the output of `explode('\n', $node->text())[0]`? try this: `$rows->flatten()->toJson();`

Comment: Output `explode('\n', $node->text())[0]` is `AUD 1 9.692,41 9.588,34BND 1 10.753,75 10.646,01CAD 1 11.173,37 11.058,20CHF 1 15.444,59 15.281,75CNH 1 2.145,88 2.124,29`

Output `$rows->flatten()->toJson();` is same like `$rows->toJson()`;

Comment: This should throw `undefined variable: $rows` inside the function and then a fatal with `Call to a member function push() on nulll`. The variable `$rows` are defined in the outside scope, and you never pass it into the function. If you want to use it in the function, you need `use`. Example: `function ($node) use ($rows) { .... }`

Comment: oh, I forgot that. I update the answer and use an arrow function for this issue. tnx @M.Eriksson

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use `$merged = array_merge(...$result);` and then `json_encode($merged);` the new array

Does this help ?

Comment: If your advised solution is to flatten the data with `array_merge(...$result);`, please do not post an answer, but flag the question as a duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/2943403)